# Search by number in zend lucene

Tags: search, indexing, numbers, zend-lucene

I read some articles about searching in indexes by numbers, but it does not work for me yet.

**more::**
i need to search in my documents by number but it does not work.

i create the docuemnt:

```
$doc1->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::UnIndexed('id', $id));
```

and i search the index:

```
$index->find("id:123");
```

but it does not work and the result is empty! i have to do that.

i tested this by changing index type to keyword,unstored,text, and unindexed

**Here is my Bootstrap::**

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault
        (new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8());

Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::setDefaultEncoding('utf-8');

Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault
        (new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_Utf8_CaseInsensitive());

Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault
          (new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum());
```

I am using this on searching and indexing. Also I commented other settings, but they also didn't work.

Comment: Could you please concrete your question?

Answer (score 0):

Type of id filed should be "Keyword", so:

```
$doc1->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Keyword('id', $id));
```

UnIndexed fields are not searchable.

Read section: [Understanding Field Types Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.search.lucene.overview.html#zend.search.lucene.index-creation.understanding-field-types)